# useEffect does not run when the dependencies are changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state-management, react-state-management

I am using React Redux for state management. I have an anonymous user and an admin. I have current user which is empty {} and I am changing it to store the user details when the admin logs in. So, in my application I want to show the admin navbar if there is a logged user and I would like to show the anonymous navbar when there is not. Currently, when the admin logs in, the navbar is changed, but when I click logout, navbar is not changed. How can I solve this issue?

This is my NavBar.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import NavBarAdmin from "./NavBarAdmin";
import NavBarAnonymous from "./NavBarAnonymous";

function NavBar() {
    const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.currentUser);
    const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState('anonymous');
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(currentUser);
        if(currentUser==null || currentUser.length==0 || currentUser == undefined){
            setCurrentView('anonymous');
        }else{
            setCurrentView('admin');
        }
    }, [currentUser])

    const handleView = () => {
        switch(currentView){
            case "anonymous": return <>
                <NavBarAnonymous/>
            </>
            case "admin":
                return <>
                <NavBarAdmin/>
            </>
        }
    }

    return(
        <>
        {handleView()}
        </>
    )
}
export default NavBar;
```

My actions.js looks like:

```
import actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export function setCurrentUser(value) {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: value
    }
}
```

actionTypes.js

```
const actionTypes = {
    SET_CURRENT_USER: 'SET_CURRENT_USER',
}
export default actionTypes;
```

configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
    const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
    const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

    const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];
    const composedEnhancers = compose(...enhancers);

    const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers);
    return store;
}
```

reducers.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export function currentUser(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER:
            
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                q: action.payload,
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    currentUser
});
```

In the logout functionality I am using:

```
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
```

And when I click logout button, {} is printed in the console, which means that the current user is set to {}, but the NavBar is not re-rendered.

Comment: In the if statement, where you check `currentUser`, none of those options is `true` because `currentUser` is `{}`. So, it sets the view to `admin`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added Object.keys(current).length === 0 check and it works now.